# To show that f-g is bijective, given the following conditions

Tags: functions

If f(x) = x, if x is rational
           = 0, if x is irrational
and g(x) = 0, if x is rational
                = x, if x is irrational
then, show that f-g is both injective and surjective. I manged to show that f-g is injective but i couldn't show how it was surjective i tried to go by basic definition by it didn't felt right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a real number. First, if it is rational, then $(f - g)(x) = f(x) - g(x) = x - 0 = x$. If it is irrational, then $(f - g)(-x) = f(-x) - g(-x)$. Since $x$ is irrational and $-1$ is rational, $-x = (-1) \cdot x$ is also irrational. Thus, $f(-x) = 0$ and $g(-x) = -x$, so $(f - g)(-x) = 0 - (-x) = x$. So, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(f - g)(y) = x$, meaning that $(f - g)$ is surjective. If you're confident in your proof that $(f - g)$ is injective, then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Note that
$$
(f - g)(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x  & \mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
  -x & \mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}.
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
Now you can check that both the function $h: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ given by $h(x) = x$ is bijective and the same holds for the function $h': \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ given by $h'(x) = -x$. Make sure to check that these functions are well-defined!